# Sitecore Commerce Minions Errors

Tags: sitecore-commerce, minion

Can any one help me to understand reason for below errors in `Sitecore commerce minions`(`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceMinions_Sc9\wwwroot\logs`).

```
17 13:58:59 ERROR ***CtxMsg.Error.IndexDoesNotExist: Text=Search Index 'CustomersScope' does not exist.***
17 13:58:59 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search Index 'CustomersScope' does not exist.
17 13:58:59 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.CreateIndexError: Text=Search index 'CustomersScope' was not created.
17 13:58:59 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search index 'CustomersScope' was not created.
17 13:58:59 ERROR IncrementalIndexMinion-Incremental Indexing failed on prepare.
29 13:59:01 ERROR ***CtxMsg.Error.IndexDoesNotExist: Text=Search Index 'OrdersScope' does not exist***.
29 13:59:01 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search Index 'OrdersScope' does not exist.
29 13:59:01 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.CreateIndexError: Text=Search index 'OrdersScope' was not created.
29 13:59:01 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search index 'OrdersScope' was not created.
29 13:59:01 ERROR IncrementalIndexMinion-Incremental Indexing failed on prepare.
57 14:01:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.IndexDoesNotExist: Text=Search Index 'OrdersScope' does not exist.
57 14:01:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search Index 'OrdersScope' does not exist.
57 14:01:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.CreateIndexError: Text=Search index 'OrdersScope' was not created.
57 14:01:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search index 'OrdersScope' was not created.
57 14:01:57 ERROR IncrementalIndexMinion-Incremental Indexing failed on prepare.
63 14:03:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.IndexDoesNotExist: Text=Search Index 'CustomersScope' does not exist.
63 14:03:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search Index 'CustomersScope' does not exist.
63 14:03:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.CreateIndexError: Text=Search index 'CustomersScope' was not created.
63 14:03:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search index 'CustomersScope' was not created.
63 14:03:57 ERROR IncrementalIndexMinion-Incremental Indexing failed on prepare.
80 14:04:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.IndexDoesNotExist: Text=Search Index 'OrdersScope' does not exist.
80 14:04:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search Index 'OrdersScope' does not exist.
80 14:04:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.CreateIndexError: Text=Search index 'OrdersScope' was not created.
80 14:04:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search index 'OrdersScope' was not created.
80 14:04:57 ERROR IncrementalIndexMinion-Incremental Indexing failed on prepare.
85 14:07:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.IndexDoesNotExist: Text=Search Index 'OrdersScope' does not exist.
85 14:07:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search Index 'OrdersScope' does not exist.
85 14:07:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.CreateIndexError: Text=Search index 'OrdersScope' was not created.
85 14:07:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search index 'OrdersScope' was not created.
85 14:07:57 ERROR IncrementalIndexMinion-Incremental Indexing failed on prepare.
61 14:08:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.IndexDoesNotExist: Text=Search Index 'CustomersScope' does not exist.
61 14:08:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search Index 'CustomersScope' does not exist.
61 14:08:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.CreateIndexError: Text=Search index 'CustomersScope' was not created.
61 14:08:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search index 'CustomersScope' was not created.
61 14:08:57 ERROR IncrementalIndexMinion-Incremental Indexing failed on prepare.
80 14:10:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.IndexDoesNotExist: Text=Search Index 'OrdersScope' does not exist.
80 14:10:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search Index 'OrdersScope' does not exist.
80 14:10:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.CreateIndexError: Text=Search index 'OrdersScope' was not created.
80 14:10:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search index 'OrdersScope' was not created.
80 14:10:57 ERROR IncrementalIndexMinion-Incremental Indexing failed on prepare.
88 14:13:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.IndexDoesNotExist: Text=Search Index 'CustomersScope' does not exist.
88 14:13:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search Index 'CustomersScope' does not exist.
88 14:13:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.CreateIndexError: Text=Search index 'CustomersScope' was not created.
88 14:13:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search index 'CustomersScope' was not created.
88 14:13:57 ERROR IncrementalIndexMinion-Incremental Indexing failed on prepare.
49 14:13:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.IndexDoesNotExist: Text=Search Index 'OrdersScope' does not exist.
49 14:13:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search Index 'OrdersScope' does not exist.
49 14:13:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.CreateIndexError: Text=Search index 'OrdersScope' was not created.
49 14:13:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search index 'OrdersScope' was not created.
49 14:13:57 ERROR IncrementalIndexMinion-Incremental Indexing failed on prepare.
98 14:16:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.IndexDoesNotExist: Text=Search Index 'OrdersScope' does not exist.
98 14:16:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search Index 'OrdersScope' does not exist.
98 14:16:57 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.CreateIndexError: Text=Search index 'OrdersScope' was not created.
98 14:16:57 ERROR PipelineAbort:Search index 'OrdersScope' was not created.
98 14:16:57 ERROR IncrementalIndexMinion-Incremental Indexing failed on prepare.
```

Comment: Check if you have PlugIn.Search.PolicySet-1.0.0.json file on your minion website? This file has references for OrdersScope, CustomersScope, CatalogIndex indexes. Also, see if your solr instance also has these indexes up and running?

Answer (score 1):

As @vlad mentioned there is some problem with your `Sitecore Commerce indexes`.

Things to check -

1. Check if you have `PlugIn.Search.PolicySet-1.0.0.json` (`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceMinions_Sc9\wwwroot\data\Environments`) file on your minion website? This file has references for `OrdersScope`, `CustomersScope`, `CatalogIndex` indexes.
2. Check if your `Solr` instance also has these indexes up and running? For that go to `PlugIn.Search.Solr.PolicySet-1.0.0.json` file and search for `SolrUrl`. It will be like this `https://localhost:8983/solr`, run this URL into the browser and check above mentioned indexes.

Answer (score 0):

This error exists because you don't have `Sitecore Commerce` Indexes: `OrdersScope`, `CustomersScope`, and probably `CatalogIndex`.

Have a look at below links and create these indexes:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/orders-scope-index.html

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/catalog-items-scope-index.html

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/customers-scope-index.html